# C# Opening a Text file from keyboard and getting a character occurance

Tags: c#, file, search, path

So basically what i'm trying to do is a console program that when you insert a string of characters(a path to a file for ex: C:\Text.txt) it would return the full path with extensions(this part works) then it would return the contents of that file and then ask you to insert a character to search for in that Text.txt file.The part with reading from a text file worked yesterday but now that does not work anymore and also the character search does not work.What i'm trying to do is basically search for a specific character in that file(for example character 'a' ( inserted from the keyboard) and then count the number of times it is in that Text.txt file . So for some reason i cannot show the content of the Text.txt file and the number of appearances does not work either.Please help me i spend way to much time on this and it does not work :(. Ty

Here is the whole code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class GetStatistics
   {
    public String GetFileDetails(String PathS)
    {
        String Space = " ";
        Console.WriteLine("Absolute: " + Path.IsPathRooted(PathS));
        Console.WriteLine("Root: " + Path.GetPathRoot(PathS));
        Console.WriteLine("Directory: " + Path.GetDirectoryName(PathS));
        Console.WriteLine("File name: " + Path.GetFileName(PathS));
        if (Path.HasExtension(PathS))
            Console.WriteLine("Extension: " + Path.GetExtension(PathS));
        Console.WriteLine("Full path: " + PathS);

        return Space;
    }

    public String ReadFromFile(String PathS)
    {
        String Extra = "\n***************************\n";
        Console.WriteLine(Extra);

        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(PathS);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            counter++;
        }


        String CharacterSearch;
        CharacterSearch = Console.ReadLine();
        var count = File.ReadLines(PathS)
            .Select((c, i) => new { Character = c, Index = i })
            .ToList()
            .Where(x => x.Character == CharacterSearch);
        file.Close();
        return Extra;
    }



}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("Introduceti un path pentru fisierul text care vreti sa il deschideti: ");
        String PathS = Console.ReadLine();
        GetStatistics G = new GetStatistics();
        Console.WriteLine(G.GetFileDetails(PathS));
        Console.WriteLine(G.ReadFromFile(PathS));
    }
}
```

}

The problem is in the ReadFromFile.

Comment: The showing of content of the file works i saved the Text file wrong. I saved it as Text.txt and i had to acces it as Text.txt.txt so only the number of occurances does not work.

Comment: So i get no errors when im trying to get the character occurance but it does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x.Character == CharacterSearch
```

It does not match the string of a portion of it and because I matching with the entire line.

If you check whether it is included in the line.

should be

```
x.Character.Contains(CharacterSearch)
```

also the number of match count (a `IEnumerable <String>`) is `count.Count()`

I think the part that displays a trace number that I needed.

```
Console.WriteLine("count:{0}", count.Count());
```

**Note : It is not the number of occurrences of the string this number because it is the matching lines.**

**for counting character**

```
String CharacterSearch;
CharacterSearch = Console.ReadLine();
var count = File.ReadLines(PathS)
    .Select((String s) => { return  s.Length - s.Replace(CharacterSearch, "").Length; })
    .Sum();
file.Close();
Console.WriteLine("count:{0}", count);
return Extra;
```

**for word and character both**

```
.Select((s) => { return  (s.Length - s.Replace(CharacterSearch, "").Length)/CharacterSearch.Length; })
```

Comment: So i changed the x.Character with what you suggested but its the same after i insert the character im searching for i get no result but a blank row.

Comment: @user2524603 Are you to display the number?

Comment: Yes the display was missing. but as you say it only displays the number of rows and my Text.txt is like this : aaaa

Comment: from what i see i think it has to do with                    CharacterSearch = Console.ReadLine();   i tryed to do it with          CharacterSearch = Console.ReadKey(); but i get a invalid operation error!

Comment: @user2524603 you are just counting the number of rows that match the current practice.

Comment: @user2524603 `CharacterSearch` is string. `Console.ReadKey()` is KeyInfo. `Console.ReadKey().KeyChar` is `char`. `string` not equal `char`.

Comment: so i edited them and made them char but im new to C# and dunno how this line would translate var count = File.ReadLines(PathS)

Comment: @user2524603 try it because i add the sample code for char version.

Answer (score 0):

basically you are not returning the count of the Character Search Count

Try This: add this method

```
       int getCharCount(String PathS)        
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Char to be searched!");
            char CharacterSearch = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            Console.ReadLine();
            int count = 0;
            String content=File.ReadAllText(PathS);
            for (int i = 0; i < content.Length; i++)
            {

                if (content[i].ToString().ToLower().Equals(CharacterSearch.ToString().ToLower()))
                    count++;
            }
            return count;
        }
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("Introduceti un path pentru fisierul text care vreti sa il deschideti: ");
    String PathS = Console.ReadLine();
    GetStatistics G = new GetStatistics();
    Console.WriteLine(G.GetFileDetails(PathS));
    Console.WriteLine(G.ReadFromFile(PathS));
    Console.WriteLine("Serch Count ="+G.getCharCount(PathS));
}
}
```